# Why is this a function declared inside the module and then used somewhere else in the same module not seen by the linker?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a function (in case anyone is interested, it is [this function](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/strtok)) in a module that looks like this

```
MODULE MYMODULE

    IMPLICIT NONE
    ! Some random stuff
    CONTAINS

        CHARACTER*255 FUNCTION strtok ( source_string, delimiters )
         [...]
        END FUNCTION strtok

        SUBROUTINE DO_SOMETHING ( )
           CHARACTER(LEN=255) :: strtok
           [...] ! 
        END SUBROUTINE DO_SOMETHING

END MODULE MYMODULE
```

The `strtok` function is a version of C's strings tokenizer, and I'll be using this function from the `DO_SOMETHING` subroutine. I need to define `strtok`, otherwise gfortran complains about it being not defined. However, if I do, and compile my code and link it to the main program, the linker complains about an undefined reference to `strtok_`. I have no idea why this is the case, as they are both in the same module and should be visible. Other functions and subroutines in the same module don't have this problem. Is this something to do with the fact that this is a character*-returning function?

Comment: If you had posted a complete module file, or even a compilable subset of one, I'd have cut and pasted it and tried compiling it.  As things stand I'd have to write several lines to fill in the gaps and I'm far too lazy to do that for you.

Comment: What is the exact error message?    Do you "use" this module from the main program?

Answer (score 6):

In the following, I'll explain using the complete example below (which you can compile and link to try things):

```
module mymodule
contains
  integer function foo ()
    foo = 1
  end function

  integer function bar ()
    integer :: foo
    bar = foo()
  end function
end module

program test
  use mymodule
  print *, bar()
end
```

In the code of function `bar`, the declaration `integer :: foo` is strictly equivalent to:

```
integer, external :: foo
```

Thus, in the code of `bar`, you are explicitly stating:

> *"there may already be a symbol of name
>   `foo` accessible to you, but from now
>   on, when I use it I mean it to be an
>   external function of this name"*

So, this is valid code, and the compiler just expect you to provide an `external` function named `foo`. Because you don't (the module function isn't external), it fails to link. You can provide an external `foo` function by adding the following code (not in the module, just at the end of the same file):

```
integer function foo ()
  foo = 42
end function
```

If you add this function body, then your code will compile, and the output will be `42` (as the external function is called, not the module function).

Also worth noting, if you comment out `integer :: foo` line in the code of `bar`, symbol `foo` will resolve to the module function, which will then be called whether or not you provide an external function named `foo` (thus, the output will be `1`).

**Conclusion:** not a compiler bug, but misuse of an old feature of the language (external declarations). To be honest, I think it's better to explicitly mark your `external` declarations as such, which would at least have highlighted the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the incomplete source code you posted, I'm thinking this may be the offending line:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=255) :: strtok
```

Since the subroutine `DO_SOMETHING` and the function `strtok` are in the same module, they automatically know about each other's definition (they have an explicit interface). This means it is not only unnecessary to redeclare the function `strtok`'s type inside `DO_SOMETHING`, but what actually happens is that this line declares a new character variable named `strtok` in the scope of subroutine `DO_SOMETHING`, overruling the module function with the same name.

Basically, inside the subroutine, the identifier `strtok` refers to a variable, so when you try to refer to a function by that name, the compiler doesn't know about it.
Hmm, now that I'm writing this, I'm starting to think this should give a compile time error, not a linking error. Still, might be worth it to try and comment out the line I mentioned and give it a go.

Comment: It doesn't declare a new variable, but the existence of an external procedure.

Comment: You're right, of course. I learned that I was mistaken some time after I had posted. I planned to correct myself, but never got around to doing it. It actually surprised me a bit that it took so much time for some one else to point it out. Thanks.