# Undefined reference to module subroutines matching an abstract interface

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to create a module which has subroutine taking another subroutine's name as argument. Here is a main program (main.for):

```
    program testmod
    use action_mod

    call main

    end program testmod
```

And here is an example of my module (action_mod.for):

```
module action_mod

abstract interface        
subroutine sub_interface(aA, aB)
    integer aA, aB
    intent(in) aA
    intent(out) aB
end subroutine
end interface

contains

subroutine main
    procedure(sub_interface) sub2,sub1
    call action(sub1)
    call action(sub2)
end subroutine

subroutine action(sub)
    procedure(sub_interface) sub
    integer argA, argB
    argA = 10
    call sub(argA, argB)
    write(*,*) argA," > ",argB
end subroutine

subroutine sub1(i,o)
    integer i,o        
    o = 100        
    return
end subroutine sub1

subroutine sub2(i,o)
    integer i,o        
    o = 200        
    return
end subroutine sub2

end module action_mod
```

Whe I compile the code with

```
gfortran -o main action_mod.for main.for
```

I get an error

```
/tmp/ccdSM11U.o: In function `__action_mod_MOD_main':
action_mod.for:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `sub1_'
action_mod.for:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `sub2_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I put subroutines `sub1(i,o)` and `sub2(i,o)` into the main.for everything works fine. However this is not what I want.

Could you help me to find a correct way of creating a module? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have much the same problem as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970798/3157076), so read answers there for more detail.  However, this case has some extra complexity which is worth considering.

In the subroutine `main` the statement

```
   procedure(sub_interface) sub2,sub1
```

says that there are *external* procedures `sub2` and `sub1`.  The module subroutines `sub1` and `sub2` of the module `action_mod` are not these external procedures.  In terms of the linked question, this is like having the declaration `character(255) strtok` "hiding" the module function `strtok`.

You should remove that statement from the subroutine.

But you have additional errors to fix.  The module subroutines `sub1` and `sub2` do not have the same interface as the abstract interface `sub_interface`.  You need to ensure that the intent attributes for the dummy arguments of `sub1` and `sub2`, `i` and `o` match, those of the `sub_interface`.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Your comment solves my problem :)