# Is there any common Fortran compiler for both f77 and f90 codes

Tags: fortran, executable

I am trying to run some of old legacy fortran code of my team.

1. I have two Fortran 77 codes (`cklib.f` and `grcom.f`) which I compile using fort77 and got two object files.
2. And I have two Fortran 90 codes (`write_counterflow_sol.f` and `read_counterflow_sol.f`) which I compile using gfortran and got another two object files.

Now, using a following makefile, I am trying to create an executable called `remail.e`

```
SOURCE_CHEMKIN = ../CHEMKIN/DATA_BASES/SOURCES
SOURCE_APPLI= ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/
SOURCES_f77 = $(SOURCE_CHEMKIN)cklib.f $(SOURCE_APPLI)grcom.f $(SOURCE_APPLI)write_counterflow_sol.f $(SOURCE_APPLI)read_counterflow_sol.f
TARGET = remail.e
OBJECTS =  $(SOURCES_f77:.f=.o)
COMPILE = f90
.f90.o :
    $(COMPILE) -o $*.o -c $*.f90
.f.o :
    $(COMPILE) -o $*.o -c $*.f
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
$(COMPILE)  $(OBJECTS) -o $@
del :
$(DELETE) $(OBJECTS)
```

but end up with the following error,

```
make: f90: Command not found
make: *** [remail.e] Error 127
```

I know there is no f90 compiler in my system, so I tried with `COMPILE=gfortran` instead of `COMPILE=f90`in the makefile and ended up with this error.

```
gfortran  ../CHEMKIN/DATA_BASES/SOURCES/cklib.o ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/grcom.o ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/write_counterflow_sol.o ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/read_counterflow_sol.o -o remail.e
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start': 
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
../CHEMKIN/DATA_BASES/SOURCES/cklib.o: In function `ckcomp_':
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0x3a4a): undefined reference to `s_cmp'
../CHEMKIN/DATA_BASES/SOURCES/cklib.o: In function `ckcpml_':
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0x3eb8): undefined reference to `pow_di'
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0x476f): undefined reference to `s_wsle'
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0x4788): undefined reference to `do_lio'
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0x478d): undefined reference to `e_wsle'
../CHEMKIN/DATA_BASES/SOURCES/cklib.o: In function `ckrat_':
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0xfac0): undefined reference to `pow_dd'
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0xfb17): undefined reference to `pow_dd'
fort77-27216-1.c:(.text+0xfef5): undefined reference to `pow_di'
../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/grcom.o: In function `MAIN__':
fort77-27073-1.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `s_copy'
fort77-27073-1.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `s_copy'
fort77-27073-1.c:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `s_wsle' 
../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/write_counterflow_sol.o: In function `write_counterflow_sol__':
fort77-27083-1.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `f_open'
fort77-27083-1.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `s_wsfe'
fort77-27083-1.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `do_fio'
../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/read_counterflow_sol.o: In function `read_counterflow_sol__':
fort77-28808-1.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `f_open'
fort77-28808-1.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `s_rsfe'
fort77-28808-1.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `do_fio'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [remail.e] Error 1
```

Also I tried with `COMPILE=f77` in the makefile and successfully executed but when I run the executable I get this following error.

```
fmt: end of file
apparent state: unit 14 named sol2
last format: (3i10)
lately reading sequential formatted external IO
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The output of `f77 -v` gives the following,

```
/usr/bin/f77: fort77 Version 1.15
/usr/bin/f77: No input files specified
```

The output of `f77 --version` gives the following,

```
/usr/bin/f77: Illegal option: --version
```

The output of `type f77` gives the following,

```
f77 is hashed (/usr/bin/f77)
```

Sorry for the long post. But any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `f77` is very likely the very same `gfortran`that you can also call by calling `gfortran`. What does `f77 -v` or `f77 --version` print?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855252/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix  `undefined reference to \`main'` means that you have no main `program`. The other undefined references are calls to some subroutines or functions you are missing.

Comment: @VladimirF, `f77 -v` prints `/usr/bin/f77: fort77 Version 1.15` `/usr/bin/f77: No input files specified` and `f77 --version` prints `/usr/bin/f77: Illegal option: --version`

Comment: @VladimirF, if f77 is same as calling gfortran, then why in the makefile if I put `COMPILE=f77` runs successfully and `COMPILE=gfortran` gives the error? And what about  `COMPILE=f90`?

Comment: AS Vladimir asks please edit the question to tell us the output of `f77 -v` and `f77 --version`.  The output  of `type f77` might be useful as well. It also looks to me as though you are compiling with gfortran, but may be linking with something else, which might be the cause of your problems.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using different compilers for different files? `gfortran` can compile most Fortran standards, and using only one compiler will avoid a lot of hastle. (Also, by "Fortran 77 codes" and "Fortran 90 codes", do you mean "fixed-form Fortran" and "free-form Fortran"?)

Comment: @IanBush, please check the edited question with the output for `f77 -v` `f77 --version` and `type f77`

Comment: @veryreverie, I am trying to re-run some old codes of my project team and reproduce the same results, which was produced like 10+ years ago. They were using both `COMPILE=f77` in one makefile and `COMPILE=f90` in another makefile but I am not sure why. All the files are fixed-form format with .f extensions. I

Comment: OK, so it is actually f2c. A really, really obsolete thing. The problem is that you can only you this for Fortran 77 code, but if you need to use also Fortran 90, it is useless for you. You cannot combine it with a Fortran 90 compiler like gfortran. There *might* be options that will fix the name mangling issue you currently see, but chances are very high that this is not the last problem from such a combination, as janneb mentions.

Comment: Also note that the `f77` in your Makefile does nothave to be the same `f77` you currently have. It might have been any other compiler. It might have been the Sun compiler on Solaris or it might have been a symlink to anything else just as your `f77` is actually `fort77` which is a repackaged `f2c`. For example, on my computer, the `f77` is actually the Oracle compiler, the successor of the Sun compiler and is now actually just a wrapper to `f90` which is identical to `sunf90`.

Comment: Any Fortran compiler should handle Fortran 90 and Fortran 77

Answer (score 3):

Gfortran supports Fortran 90, which is a superset of Fortran 77. Gfortran also supports several popular language extensions that were commonly used before Fortran 90.

Trying to use several different compilers to compile a single application will likely lead to problems due to different runtime libraries and different ABI's.

So, forget about fort77 and g77 and other obsolete compilers.

Comment: _almost_ a superset.

Comment: @francescalus Considering how confused the OP appears to be about Fortran programming, I thought it best to not get bogged down in pedantry about a few corner cases. But yes, strictly speaking you're correct of course.

Comment: @janneb, thanks for your answer. Its very clear!!

Answer (score 1):

So to be specific. Most of the current errors you see in your post are from the missing fort77 runtime library. The code you compiled with `f77` translated its `open`, `read`, `write`,... statements to calls to functions implemented in C in the runtime library. Eg., `f_open` is called where the `open` statement was invoked, the `pow_dd` function is called where some power like `a**b` was invoked when both a and b are double precision, `pow_di` is for `a**i` where i is an integer, and so on.

These functions are incompatible with gfortran-compiled code. The I/O part of the library is incompatible. The files opened in fort77 code cannot be used by `read` or `write` in gfortran and vice versa.

You *might* be able to get most of the error messages go away by linking the runtime library. Perhaps by `-lf2c`. However, that does not mean the code will work correctly. It might in simple cases, but it won't in general.

You should really compile everything with `gfortran` as janneb answered. If your code is incompatible with gfortran, it is very likely not standard conforming and will have to be fixed.

For specific advice on such possible fixes you have to create questions with the specific errors, such as [How to solve the "fmt: end of file, last format: (3i10)" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615513/how-to-solve-the-fmt-end-of-file-last-format-3i10-error) but with a full [mcve]. We really need a full code that we can test with all the necessary data it needs. The code must be also reasonably short. Be aware that isolating such small independent code is often hard work, but it is necessary.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer. Now, things are getting clearer to me. So what I am gonna do is to uninstall fort77 and try to compile and run everything with gfortran and solve the errors on the way. Thanks again.