# "undefined reference" error when trying to compile a fortran program with external dependencies using ifort

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, hdf5, intel-fortran

I am using the following command to compile my fortran program, which is the last line of the result of the `hdf5 h5fc` command on my `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64` machine (added newlines for legibility):

```
<path_to_my_intel_oneapi_folder>/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin/intel64/ifort -shlib 
-I<path_to_my_hdf5_1.12.2>/include 
-L<path_to_my_hdf5_1.12.2>/lib 
-lhdf5_fortran 
-lhdf5 
-I<path_to_my_mpich_4.0.2>/include 
-L<path_to_my_mpich_4.0.2>/lib 
-lmpifort -Wl,-rpath -Wl,<path_to_my_mpich_4.0.2>/lib 
-lmpi <path_to_my_intel_oneapi_folder>/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin/intel64/ifort
```

I built `hdf5` with `cmake` instead of `autotools`, which has [slight differences in the resulting installation](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/cmake-and-autotools-builds-differences/4277) but should still work on my current machine.
Linking after successfully compiling results in a large number of `undefined reference` errors, such as following:

```
ld: /path_to_my_file/my_file.o: in function `hdf5_utilities_mp_hdf5_openfile_':
my_file.f90:(.text+0xcbf8): undefined reference to `h5global_mp_h5p_file_access_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcc0a): undefined reference to `h5p_mp_h5pcreate_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcc2a): undefined reference to `h5global_mp_h5f_acc_trunc_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcc45): undefined reference to `h5f_mp_h5fcreate_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcc63): undefined reference to `h5global_mp_h5f_acc_rdwr_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcc79): undefined reference to `h5f_mp_h5fopen_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcc93): undefined reference to `h5global_mp_h5f_acc_rdonly_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xcca9): undefined reference to `h5f_mp_h5fopen_f_'
ld: my_file.f90:(.text+0xccc4): undefined reference to `h5p_mp_h5pclose_f_'
```

The path `<path_to_my_hdf5_1.12.2>/lib`, which is specified in the `-L` flag of the abovementioned `ifort` command, contains the files `libhdf5_fortran.so.200.1.1` and `libhdf5_fortran.a` which contain the references to the hdf functions that cannot be linked, such as `h5global_mp_h5p_file_access_f_`.
I assume that those errors are related to the following command, which is located in a different file that `my_file.f90` makes use of:

```
module HDF5_utilities
  use HDF5
...
integer(HID_T) function HDF5_openFile(fileName,mode,parallel)
  ...
  integer(HID_T) :: plist_id
  integer :: hdferr
  call H5Pcreate_f(H5P_FILE_ACCESS_F, plist_id, hdferr)
  ...
```

This problem has started occuring since I created a new `ifort hdf5` setup on my machine and my source files had no issues compiling prior to this, so I assume this is related to the way `hdf5` is currently installed on my system. I installed `hdf5` with `cmake` and used `mpich` as a dependency and am am using the [spack package manager](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to install those packages. `hdf5` is fetched from the `tar.gz` file from [this source](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.12/hdf5-1.12.2/src/) and compiled using the intel compiler from the [intel oneapi package](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_systems/inteloneapipackage.html).

Comment: The fact that `use HDF5` compiles means that the compiler can find the `hdf5.mod` module file. However, you also have to make sure that the linker can find the `.so` or `.a` libraries. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855252/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix Try compiling on the command line and setting the `-L` flag manually to point where the library is actually installed.