# Compiling C and Fortran using iFort

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to call a simple "Hello World" code from C using Fortran. When I compile using iFort, it is giving me "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HELLO referenced in function MAIN__"

**C Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_(){

    printf("Hello World :) \n");
}
```

**Fortran Code:**

```
       program Fortran_C_Link_Test
C
      implicit None
C
      call hello()
C
      stop
      end
```

How I Compiled:

```
cl -c c_src.c
```

to generate the c_src.obj object file

```
ifort -c fortran_src.f
```

to generate the fortran_src.obj object file

```
ifort -o program c_src.obj fortran_src.obj
```

to generate the executable

Comment: Please show how you are linking, and be sure to read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66855252/3157076) and its answers.

Comment: Just updated with compiler options

Comment: It seems your compiler expects a different name for the symbol of your external function/subroutine. Are these really the complete compiler options you are showing? Is this on MS Windows? Try `void HELLO(){` but also learn how modern C and Fortran interoperability is done using `bind(C)`. You should not need to do any assumptions about `hello` being `hello_` or `_hello` or `_hello_` or `HELLO` or `HELLO_` or whatever else the compiler is liking to use today.