# Open netcdf with gfortran in Mac environment, Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 occurs

Tags: fortran, gfortran, netcdf

I'm a Mac user
I'm trying to create a netcdf using gfortran, but I get the following error
My Mac is using an M1 chip

Below is the Fortran code I made

```
   PROGRAM net2
        use netcdf

        IMPLICIT NONE

        INTEGER :: status, ncid
        INTEGER :: nx, ny, ii, jj, x, y, xx, yy
        REAL, DIMENSION(239, 239) :: field
        REAL, DIMENSION(239, 239) :: eqa
        INTEGER :: dimid_lon, dimid_lat, dimid_time
        INTEGER :: varid_lat, varid_lon, varid_field, varid_eqa, varid_time
        REAL :: pi, lat_array(239), lon_array(239)
        PARAMETER (pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0))

        status = nf90_create('new.nc', NF90_NETCDF4, ncid)
        call check(status, 'open')

        nx = 239
        ny = 239

        status = nf90_def_dim(ncid, 'longitude', nx, dimid_lon)
        status = nf90_def_dim(ncid, 'latitude', ny, dimid_lat)
        status = nf90_def_dim(ncid, 'time', nf90_unlimited, dimid_time)

        status = nf90_def_var(ncid, 'longitude', NF90_FLOAT, [dimid_lon], varid_lon)
        status = nf90_def_var(ncid, 'latitude', NF90_FLOAT, [dimid_lat], varid_lat)
        status = nf90_def_var(ncid, 'time', NF90_FLOAT, [dimid_time], varid_time)
        status = nf90_def_var(ncid, 'field', NF90_FLOAT, [dimid_lat, dimid_lon], varid_field)
        status = nf90_def_var(ncid, 'eqa', NF90_FLOAT, [dimid_lat, dimid_lon], varid_eqa)

        status = nf90_put_att(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, 'note', 'Test of Created NetCDF file')
        status = nf90_put_att(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, 'ISIC', 15)
        status = nf90_put_att(ncid, varid_lon, 'units', 'degree_east')
        status = nf90_put_att(ncid, varid_lat, 'units', 'degree_north')
        status = nf90_put_att(ncid, varid_field, '_FillValue', -2e8)
        status = nf90_put_att(ncid, varid_eqa, '_FillValue', -2e8)

        lat_array = [(jj * (360./ny), jj=0, ny-1)]
        lon_array = [((ii * (180./(nx-1)) - 90.), ii=0, nx-1)]
        do jj = 1, ny
                do ii = 1, nx
                field(ii, jj) = sin(lon_array(ii) * pi/180.) * cos(lat_array(jj) * pi/180.)
                end do
        end do

        do yy = 1, ny
                do xx = 1, nx
                        eqa(xx, yy) = x**2 + y**2
                end do
        end do

        status = nf90_put_var(ncid, varid_lon, lon_array)
        status = nf90_put_var(ncid, varid_lat, lat_array)
        status = nf90_put_var(ncid, varid_field, field)
        status = nf90_put_var(ncid, varid_eqa, eqa)

        status = nf90_close(ncid)
        call check(status, 'close')

contains
        SUBROUTINE check(status, loc)
                INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: status
                CHARACTER, INTENT(in) :: loc
                if (status /= NF90_NOERR) then
                WRITE(*, *) "ERROR at", loc
                WRITE(*, *) NF90_STRERROR(status)

                end if
        END SUBROUTINE check
END PROGRAM net2
```

Compiling this code will result in the following error

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_close", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_create", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_def_dim", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_def_var_manydims", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_att_one_fourbyteint", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_att_one_fourbytereal", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_att_text", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_var_1d_fourbytereal", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_var_2d_fourbytereal", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccHtjGFn.o
  "___netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror", referenced from:
      _check.0 in ccHtjGFn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know how to solve errors that I haven't seen on Windows

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855252/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix and [mcve]. You have to show us what you are doing. You always must show which exact command produxed the error messages you show and the complete output. See also [ask]. It is necessary to provide more details, especially how you are linking the code together and with libraries like NetCDF.

Comment: I have actually.no idea what should "Open netcdf with gfortran" or "trying to create a netcdf". Are you trying to compile the library or use the library in your code? Really, we need the exact commands.

Comment: *"Compiling this code will result in the following error"* Show the **exact commands** you are using for compiling. Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855252/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix ?

Comment: The purpose of what I do is to make the netcdf file Fortran. In Windows, when compiling gfortran, it ran when I added nc-config fflags and flibs paths. But that's not the case with MacBooks.
I added the same nc-config cflags and libs path, but it didn't run. It's a command I executed. 

gfortran net_write.f90 -I/Users/lsh/miniforge3/include -L/Users/lsh/miniforge3/lib -lnetcdf

I installed both netcdf-cxx and netcdf-fortran using conda install

Comment: Do not use comments for important information, edit your question to include the commands.

Comment: Where is the library installed? Is a libnetcdf.dyld or a similar file located in `/Users/lsh/miniforge3/lib`?

Comment: The file exists

Comment: How did you get the netcdf library?

Comment: I installed netcdf as a brew. In the case of netcdf-fortran, it was installed using conda install

Comment: Well the thing that jumps out for me is the line "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" - are you sure the correct version of the library is installed. I don't use apple stuff so I can't tell you how to find this out.

Comment: You should install both from the same source. And make sure that what you are installing is for ARM64, or specifically for Apple M1 or M2.

Comment: *"The file exists"*  Is it really.in that directory? That directory is for conda. Isn't in some homebrew directory?