# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol DGEEV referenced in function MAIN__ New_code.obj

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, visual-studio-2022

I have been writing code in Microsoft Visual Studio in Fortran language and getting this error.
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol DGEEV referenced in function MAIN__       New_code.obj
Please help me resolve this issue.

[this is the error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IySKi.png)

Comment: [The object file or library that contains the definition of the symbol isn't linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=msvc-170#possible-causes)

Comment: And in this particular case you almost certainly want to link in LAPACK.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855252/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix I may mark this as a duplicate

Comment: Also **please** include all errors as text, **do not** link to screen shots

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. If the duplicate link does not resolve your problem, you have to 1. show all error messages as text, not as pictures, 2. show the exact commands you are running (also as text), 3. show the detailed configuration of your build system, including how you link with the LAPACK library. You have to link with this library. See also [ask] and [mre].